# Is it true that $L^2_0(\mathcal{G},\mathbb{P})\oplus L^2_0(\mathcal{H},\mathbb{P}) = L^2_0(\sigma(\mathcal{G},\mathcal{H}),\mathbb{P})$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

If $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ is a probability space, define $L^2_0(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}):=\{f\in L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})\ | \ \int_\Omega f\operatorname{d}\mathbb{P}=0\}$.

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and let $\mathcal{G},\mathcal{H}$ sub-$\sigma$-algebras of $\mathcal{F}$ that are $\mathbb{P}$-independent. Then it is immediate that $$L^2_0(\Omega,\mathcal{G},\mathbb{P})\perp L^2_0(\Omega,\mathcal{H},\mathbb{P}),$$
so, denoting with $\sigma(\mathcal{G},\mathcal{H})$ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{H}$, from $L^2_0(\Omega,\mathcal{G},\mathbb{P})\subset L^2_0(\Omega,\sigma(\mathcal{G},\mathcal{H}),\mathbb{P})$ and $L^2_0(\Omega,\mathcal{H},\mathbb{P})\subset L^2_0(\Omega,\sigma(\mathcal{G},\mathcal{H}),\mathbb{P})$, it follows that:
$$L^2_0(\Omega,\mathcal{G},\mathbb{P})\oplus L^2_0(\Omega,\mathcal{H},\mathbb{P})$$ 
is a closed subspace of
$$L^2_0(\Omega,\sigma(\mathcal{G},\mathcal{H}),\mathbb{P}).$$
So the question: is it also true that
$$L^2_0(\Omega,\mathcal{G},\mathbb{P})\oplus L^2_0(\Omega,\mathcal{H},\mathbb{P}) = L^2_0(\Omega,\sigma(\mathcal{G},\mathcal{H}),\mathbb{P})?$$

Comment: I don't know the answer, but  my guess is that the left side restricted to bounded measurable functions need not be an algebra whereas the right side is.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: I started also to think so... I'm working out a specific counterexample

Comment: In other words: is any $\sigma(\mathcal F, \mathcal G)$-measurable function the sum of a $\mathcal F$-measurable function and a $\mathcal G$-measuruable function.  This is wildly false.  Functions of two variables are much more complicated than that!  Even in the plane, where the two coordinates are independent for Lebesgue measure, it is not true that a function $f(x,y)$ of two variables can be written as a sum $f_1(x)+f_2(y)$.

Comment: @GEdgar much more illuminating than my counterexample. If you write it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In other words: is any $\sigma(\mathcal F, \mathcal G)$-measurable function the sum of a $\mathcal F$-measurable function and a $\mathcal G$-measuruable function.  This is wildly false.  Functions of two variables are much more complicated than that!

Even in the plane, where the two coordinates are independent for Lebesgue measure, it is not true that a (mean zero square-integrable) function $f(x,y)$ of two variables can be written as a sum $f_1(x)+f_2(y)$.

Explanation:  Write $\mathcal B_1$ for the Borel  sets in $\mathbb R$ and $\mathcal B_2$ for the Borel sets in $\mathbb R^2$.  Let
$$
\mathcal F = \{ A \times \mathbb R : A \in \mathcal B_1\}
\\
\mathcal G = \{ \mathbb R \times A : A \in \mathcal B_1\}
$$
These are independent with respect to $2$-dimensional Lebesgue measure.
A function $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable if and only if there is a $\mathcal B_1$-measurable function $f_1 : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ with $f(x,y) = f_1(x)$ for all $x,y$.  Similarly, $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable if and only if there is a $\mathcal B_1$-measurable function $f_2 : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ with $f(x,y) = f_2(y)$ for all $x,y$.

Answer (score 1):

What follows is a counterexample.

- $\Omega:=\{a,b,c,d\}$;
- $\mathcal{G}:=\{\emptyset , \{a,d\}, \{b,c\}, \Omega\}$;
- $\mathcal{H}:=\{\emptyset , \{b,d\}, \{a,c\}, \Omega\}$;
- $\mathbb{P} :2^\Omega\rightarrow[0,1]$ the uniform probability on $\Omega$.

Then from $$\mathbb{P}(\{a,d\}\cap\{b,d\})=\mathbb{P}(\{d\})=\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}=\mathbb{P}(\{a,d\})\mathbb{P}(\{b,d\}),$$
also the other relations to check the independence follows, and then $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{H}$ are $\mathbb{P}$-independent.
Also, notice that $\sigma(\mathcal{G},\mathcal{H})=2^\Omega$.

Now:

- $L^2_0(\Omega,\mathcal {G},\mathbb{P})=\{\lambda 1_{\{a,d\}}-\lambda 1_{\{b,c\}}\ |\ \lambda\in\mathbb{R}\}$;
- $L^2_0(\Omega,\mathcal {H},\mathbb{P})=\{\mu 1_{\{b,d\}}-\mu 1_{\{a,c\}}\ |\ \mu\in\mathbb{R}\}$;
- $L^2_0(\Omega,\mathcal {G},\mathbb{P})\oplus L^2_0(\Omega,\mathcal {H},\mathbb{P})=\{\lambda 1_{\{a,d\}}-\lambda 1_{\{b,c\}} + \mu 1_{\{b,d\}}-\mu 1_{\{a,c\}}\ |\ \lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{R}\}$;
- $1_{\{a\}}-1_{\{c\}}\in L^2_0(\Omega,\sigma(\mathcal {G},\mathcal {H}),\mathbb{P})$,

but:
$$1_{\{a\}}-1_{\{c\}}\notin L^2_0(\Omega,\mathcal {G},\mathbb{P})\oplus L^2_0(\Omega,\mathcal {H},\mathbb{P}).$$
In fact, if this is not the case, than the following system has a solution:
\begin{cases}
               \lambda - \mu =1\\
               -\lambda + \mu = 0 \\
               -\lambda-\mu = -1 \\
               \lambda + \mu = 0, \\
            \end{cases}
however, this system has not a solution.